# Форматирование текста для JTextField

Tags: java, форматирование, jtextfield

У меня есть консоль, JTextField, в которую выводится String out, когда мне нужно дописать текст, я добавляю в эту переменную \n и необходимый текст, затем опять вывожу out на JTextField.

```
String out="";
JTextField console = new JTextField():
out=out+"\n Пример";
console.setText(out);
```

Мне нужно, что бы одни строчки выравнивались по правому краю, а другие по левому. И желательно, у них был разный цвет. Подойдут любые идеи, даже с полной переработкой системы вывода. По типу:

```
Так               
                                                                  И вот так................
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте JTextPane с html внутри